# different results while testing the app in emulator and cellphone

Tags: java, android

I have two problems.

At first I am adding two relative layouts which will be needed to ask my question.

**(a)**

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:menu="@menu/main_menu"
            app:title="Hello World" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtMessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Hello World"
        android:textColor="#adb015"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**(b)**

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtMessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Hello World"
        android:textColor="#adb015"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**(c)**
**Now I am providing the mainActivity.java file code .I will also need that to ask my question.**

```java
package com.example.helloworld;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView textView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);
        textView.setText(getString(R.string.hello));


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.settings_menu) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "settings selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        } else {
            if (super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) return true;
            else return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Question  1 :**  I was testing my app with both emulator and my android phone. When I am using  (a) and (c) then the menubar and the settings icon is showing in both emulator and the phone ,and a 'Hello' text is showing at the center of the screen .

but, when I am using (b) and (c) ,then the same thing is showing in the emulator as before ,but nothing is showing except a text 'Hello' when I am testing with my phone.for the same code why two different results are coming?And what to do now?Please help me.

**Question 2  :**  When I am using  (a) and (c) then the menubar and the settings icon is showing in both emulator and the phone ,and a 'Hello' text is showing at the center of the screen .But the Toast message is only working in the emulator and not in my phone.As I am learning app development from last two weeks,I have test several Toast messages in my mobile.All of them worked properly.Only while builing the menubar this problem is coming .Please help me.

**I am also enclosing my style.xml file which I changed a little searching internet  -----**

```java
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Base.Theme.HelloWorld" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight">
        <!-- Customize your light theme here. -->
        <!-- <item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_light_primary</item> -->
    </style>


    <style name="Theme.HelloWorld" parent="Base.Theme.HelloWorld" />
</resources>
```

As a beginner I tried my Level best .I have tried to solve it for hours.But at last I could not understand.here's I am mentioning what I tried---
I asked many questions on these issues to both chatgpt and bard.
I made some changes in  the style.xml file as well as I replaced relative layout (b) with (a).
After I did this the menubar and settings menu came to visible in my mobile also.